# User should not be able to insert/update if that obejct is not active

Tags: workflow, validation-rule

can i achieve this functionality using validation rule by creating Is_active field in the object ?
can anyone suggest me ......

Comment: What do you mean with an object not being active? What do you mean with creating Is_active files in the object?

Comment: am sorry ,its is_active field...here i have teacher object,so user should not able to insert/update if  teacher is not active .......

Answer (score 2):

You can write a trigger on Teacher object to avoid all DML(insert/Update) operation, This will be base on is_Active field

Answer (score 1):

You can either achive this by validation rules or before insert/update trigger using

```
sObject.adderror('XXXXX');
```

This way the user is notified so they know why they can't insert/update the object if you just avoid it without showing any message can be confusing.